# Ruby multiple OR conditions

Tags: ruby, or-condition

In ruby, is there a more concise way of expressing multiple OR conditions in an if statement?

For example this is the code I have:

```
if call_type == "GPRS" || call_type == "SMS" || call_type == "MMS" || call_type == "USSD" || call_type == "TELEPHONY"
  #do something
end
```

There will be more OR conditions and I don't want to write like this multiple times. Is there a better way to express this in ruby 2.1.0 ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is this not a duplicate?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use [`Array#include?`](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-include-3F):

```
if %w(GPRS SMS MMS USSD TELEPHONY).include? call_type
  # ...
end
```

Or a [`case` expression](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-case+Expression):

```
case call_type
when 'GPRS', 'SMS', 'MMS', 'USSD', 'TELEPHONY'
  # ...
end
```

Or a [regular expression](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html):

```
if call_type =~ /^(GPRS|SMS|MMS|USSD|TELEPHONY)$/
  # ...
end
```

As [noted by cremno](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28690514/ruby-multiple-or-conditions/28690547?noredirect=1#comment45674234_28690547), `^` and `$` match beginning and end of line. You can use `\A` and `\z` instead if `call_type` contains multiple lines.

Comment: You might want to use `\A`/`\z` (beginning/end of string) instead of `^`/`$` (beginning/end of line) to have the same behavior as your other examples (which don't accept `"ABC\nSMS"`, for example).

Comment: If `arr = %w{ a b c }` you can write `case('b'); when *arr; puts 'hi'; end #=> "hi"` and `r = Regexp.new('^('+arr.join('|')+')$') #=> /^(a|b|c)$/; 'b'[r] #=> "b"; 'd'[r] #=> nil`. This is convenient when `arr` is large.

Comment: Your last comment is interesting.  I would have thought `/^#{Regexp.union(arr).to_s}$/` (which works) would have been required, but `to_s` is not needed. Why?